# One iota of what they are capable

Tags: cleft-constructions

Read the following

"Did they wait until it was too late to make from their life even **one iota of what they are capable**"

I don't understand how they made this 'what' clause there without using of at the end.
It has to be 'what they are capable'.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. There's an "of" before "what", so you don't need one at the end. But no idea why you say it has to be what it already is.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with you. Focusing on the bolded part in question, it has the form:

> [measure/quantity] of [thing]

As in:

> **one slice** of **pizza**
>
> **a high degree** of **brick-laying ability**

Now, "one iota" seems fine as the quantity. The question is, is this a valid description of a thing:

> what they are capable

I'd say it is not. I'm sure someone else can give you the formal reason, but it seems wrong to me, because the following seems right:

> what they are capable of

As does:

> that of which they are capable

Either way, you need that "of" -- i.e. one as part of the [thing] description, in addition to one connecting the [measure/amount] to the [thing].

Answer (score -4):

Grammar punctuation prefers the Object coming after the Preposition.

"of what they are capable" is more correct than "what they are capable of"

Comment: I can't resist, but that is the kind of offensive impertinence, up with which I will not put. 

Comment: In other words, that rule about prepositions, as well as the rule about how we are not to ever split infinitives, are not really worth taking heed of. That said, I must confess that because many people make the mistake of thinking the rules are valid, I do often find myself labouring so as not egregiously to split infinitives, and, for that same reason, the rule about prepositions is one attention to which I do often try to pay.

Comment: @tkp Yeah I mean, in speaking you'll probably put the preposition at the end, because people don't plan their whole sentence structure in their head on-the-fly. But like you also said, it's a grammar rule. So, if you're following rules, you'd say "it's not worth taking heed of [that rule]" as opposed to "[that rule] is not really worth taking heed of."

Comment: I was being kind in referring to it as a rule at all. Of course exactly what constitutes a rule in language is far from clear. I mean, is a rule being broken when someone uses "momentarily" to mean "in a moment" and not "for a moment"? Says who? And is a rule being broken when a sentence is started with the word "And"? Whose rule? I'd have to say that given how common both of those are--and despite the fact that as a Brit, living in the US, I find the momentarily thing headsplodingly annoying--I'd have to say no. Ditto the preposition rule. It's not a rule. If you disagree, well says who?

Comment: Interesting discussion about this stuff in the Wikipedia article, [Common English usage misconceptions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_English_usage_misconceptions#Grammar).

Comment: @tkp thanks for the link, it's good information. As the link said, the rule of "don't end in prepositions" is still taught in schools up to this very day. I guess I'm just a product of the system. With that being said, if the majority of people feel it's incorrect - who is to say whether that justifies it as a rule or not?